# AngularJS ng-attr-title has no effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code -

```
    <div ng-attr-title="{{myProductName}}!" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 align-center whitecolor fontSize28 headerText">
          {{ myProductName}}!
    </div>
```

and in my HTML elements on chrome developer tool:

```
 <div ng-attr-title="{{ myProductName}}!" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 align-center whitecolor fontSize28 headerText ng-binding" title="Welcome to , !">
          Welcome to, !
    </div>
```

But, the "Product Name (Say "ABCD" is not displaying. What might be the problem? I use AJS 1.3.x

My controller:

```
 products.productName = $http.defaults.headers.common[PROD_CONST.PROD_NAME];
        if (products.productName !== 'SM_PROD') {
            products.productName = products.productName;
        } else {
            products.productName = '';
        }
```

Comment: does `$scope.myProductName` actually have a value in the controller?

Comment: how can i debug and chcek that? Sorry I am new to AJS. I can't use any chrome plugins except developer tools to debug it

Comment: it's rather tough for anyone to help you debug this code with the minimal example you provided; you haven't shown where your controller is defined, the contents of the controller, or any other code to indicate what `myProductName` represents or where it is set.

Comment: thanks a ton. I found the issue is "" (Moving to else case), added my controller